# I need to read HKEY_CURRENTUSER from javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I have code which works perfectly in IE but it doesn't work in chrome and firefox.

Any idea?

Comment: That sounds very unlikely. Can you show some code?

Comment: @lonesomeday: IE can access just about anything via ActiveX depending on the security zone of the document (commonly used for intranet stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: You can't... The reason it works in IE is that you're probably accessing it using activeX which is not used by any other browser

HKEY_CURRENTUSER is not even a cross platform value (windows only, I guess), so even if you could read environment variables (which really is a security hole) it would not exist on any other system.

EDIT: The real question is what do you want to read it for? I assume the value is the name of the logged in user. If you want it for a personalized greeting or something, why don't you just ask the user, and store it in a permanent cookie?

If you need it for some kind of authentication related stuff in an intranet site, you're probably relying on a lot of other IE-only features, which won't work in any other browser anyway (and if you do, I'm sure many developers would say: "you're doing it wrong").

Comment: i want to check whether an exe exist or not ..means key has path of an exe

Comment: Still, why do you need this in a webapp? BTW, the concept of .exe files is also a windows concept, you're clearly trying to do something very tightly coupled with Windows anyway, why do you try to make it cross browser compatible then?

Comment: well i want my users to run my exe from any browser they have....... not just from IE

Comment: Who runs executables directly from a browser anyway? I still don't really understand what you want to do. Determine if they already have a program installed so that clueless users don't reinstall it all the time? - In which case, perhaps you could assume that users not using the default "internet" button in Windows, actually know what they're doing. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your code is using IE only functionality, probably using an [`ActiveX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) object.

You can't access the client registry using Firefox or Chrome. They do not support `ActiveX`.

Answer (score 2):

To do the same on Firefox or Chrome I think you need to use a [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In pure Javascript running in a modern day browser, **NO**. This would be a huge security issue. Browsers do everything in their power to avoid that sites you visit has access to your local filesystem. And that's a good thing. Otherwise we would all have to reinstall our computers every other day ;)

Comment: Reinstalling, isn't that what windows users are doing all day long? ;P

Comment: I think the standard is about once every 3-6 months ;)

Comment: I only installed Vista once and 7 once too :) But I need to reinstall Linux every time I break it :P It's not Linux degenerates as Windows used to do but it's me who brake things I don't know how to fix.